# Joining two columns to create a list of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I currently have two columns that need to be compared. Col A, Sheet 1 & Col A, Sheet 2.

Sheet 1 contains:

```
A      B       C
5000   Apples  WI
6182   Oranges NY
7271   Grapes  MN
2293   Peanuts FL
```

Sheet 2 contains:

```
A
4032
5233
7271
2293
```

Should Receive Results like....

```
7271   Grapes  MN
2293   Peanuts FL
```

I need to only display the results that contain the same number as Sheet 2. Is there a better way then loading Sheet 2 into an array, and comparing it against each cell in Sheet 1?

```
    'For i = 1 to Sheet1LastRow

    Sheet2Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet2Array = Range("A2:A" & Sheet2LastRow).Value
            For i = LBound(Sheet2Array, 1) To UBound(Sheet2Array, 1)

    'if cell = Sheet2Array(i, 1)
     '....
    'End if

    Next i

   'Next Cell sheet 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use `=VLOOKUP()`?

Comment: I guess I am not too familiar with VLOOKUP. If it could be implemented by VBA and work between two different workbooks, that would be an option. Could it be implemented by VBA to work with X rows of data in Col A on both sheets?

Answer (score 3):

This is the core function of `=VLOOKUP()`.

Syntax is:

```
=VLOOKUP(
         compare this cell, 
         to the cells in the leftmost column of this range,
         returning the corresponding value from this column index,
         true/false for range lookup (just leave this false if you aren't sure)
 )
```

On sheet 2, in cell B1 you would place `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,False)` and in C1 you would place `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:C,3,False)`

This function works between worksheets just as well as between workbooks (but you will have to enable links and be mindful of changes to both workbooks). No VBA is required, this is a simple inline function.

Extending on this, you'll probably get `#N/A` errors on for values that don't exist on your source table. Wrap the formula in `=IFERROR( your vlookup() function , "" )` to replace any errors with a blank cell.

Answer (score 1):

From your question and sample data it is evident that what you are looking for as an output is a column with matching data in a contiguous block of cells without any blanks or errors in between.

If you wish to use formula approach, then it can be achieved using a slightly complex INDEX & MATCH functions in an Array Formula. Once you have the matching data in contiguous cells in a column, then simply apply VLOOKUP to fetch the rest of the two columns from your master table in Sheet1.

Here's how.   Below are two screenshots of Sheet1 & Sheet2.

[image]

[image]

Sheet1 has your master table in Columns A, B & C, Sheet2 has your list to be matched with  Column A from Sheet1

Now in Sheet2 in say Cell C1 Put the following Array Formula

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,0)),"",MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,0)),ROW(1:1)))}
```

Put this formula without the Braces and from within the Formula Bar press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to create an array formula and drag it down till you get error in cells or length of your list to be matched. Now all rows above error cells have the matching cells from Column A of Sheet1.

Just clear the error cells and you have the list in contigious block of cells.

Now in D1 enter relatively simple VLOOKUP formula to fetch the next matching column from Sheet1

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,Sheet1!$A$1:$C$4,2,FALSE)
```

And in E1 put the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,Sheet1!$A$1:$C$4,3,FALSE)
```

and drag both down.  You have your list as desired.

You may use Excel's built in Evaluate Formula option to evaluate the INDEX MATCH combination to get a feel of how this works. It creates an array of matching row numbers and picks the first then second, then third smallest number as you drag down the formula.

Two limitations here are that the data shall be returned in the order in which it exists in Master Table and not how it's in the table 'to be matched' and in case you have more than 1 matching cells, the first shall be returned.